# Issues running AWS sample application

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am currently trying to run the AWSDynamoDB sample application that is provided by Amazon and following the instructions provided. However, I get the following error when trying to run it:

```
'AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h' file not found
```

I'm not sure where exactly I'm going wrong. Any tips or pointers are appreciated. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: what aws sdk are you using? Can you include the link of the documentation that you are referring?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBObjectMapper-Sample/Objective-C) Here is the documentation I am using to set up the sample.